# Reference vs setting a local variable

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Consider the two cases:

1. `Object& obj = *getObjectPtr();`
2. `Object obj = *getObjectPtr();`

What is the difference between these two in C++?

Comment: This is covered in any introductory C++ book: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line (1) is semantically equivalent to `Object *obj_p = getObjectPtr()`, and then using `*obj_p`.  The reference behaves like a pointer, but without pointer syntax.  More examples here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29

Line (2) will cause a new `Object` to be created, and the `Object` at the memory address `getObjectPtr()` to be *copied* into it via (probably) `Object`'s copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`Object& obj = *getObjectPtr();` - obj will hold a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29) to the original object that is returned by `getObjectPtr()`.

`Object obj = *getObjectPtr();` - obj will hold a copy of the original object that is returned by `getObjectPtr()`.

Comment: The first refers to the object *inside the function*, the second makes a copy of the object.